# Build a tic-tac-toe

Tags: java, algorithm

I am designing a dose game that I have encountered several problems:

- I do not want the pre-selected house to be re-selected. How do I do this?
- And when I use the cleanScreen method, the console does not clear, why?

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int count = 9;

  ```
        String one = "1";
        String two = "2";
        String three = "3";
        String four = "4";
        String five = "5";
        String six = "6";
        String seven = "7";
        String eight = "8";
        String nine = "9";


        for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(one + " | " + two + " | " + three);
            System.out.println("---------");
            System.out.println(four + " | " + five + " | " + six);
            System.out.println("---------");
            System.out.println(seven + " | " + eight + " | " + nine);

            int num1 = sc.nextInt();
            cleanScreen();
            switch (num1)
            {
                case 1 -> one = "X";
                case 2 -> two = "X";
                case 3 -> three = "X";
                case 4 -> four = "X";
                case 5 -> five = "X";
                case 6 -> six = "X";
                case 7 -> seven = "X";
                case 8 -> eight = "X";
                case 9 -> nine = "X";
                default -> System.out.println("Enter a number from one to nine");
            }

            System.out.println(one + " | " + two + " | " + three);
            System.out.println("---------");
            System.out.println(four + " | " + five + " | " + six);
            System.out.println("---------");
            System.out.println(seven + " | " + eight + " | " + nine);


            if (one.equals("X") & two.equals("X") & three.equals("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN X");
            }
            else if (four.equals("X") & five.equals("X") & six.equals("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN X");
            }
            else if (seven.equals("X") & eight.equals("X") & nine.equals("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN X");
            }
            else if (one.equals("X") & four.equals("X") & seven.equals("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN X");
            }
            else if (two.equals("X") & five.equals("X") & eight.equals("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN X");
            }
            else if (one.equals("X") & five.equals("X") & nine.equals("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN X");
            }
            else if (three.equals("X") & five.equals("X") & seven.equals("X"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN X");
            }
            Random Tas = new Random();

            int num2 = Tas.nextInt(1,10);
            System.out.println(num2);

            cleanScreen();
            switch (num2)
            {
                case 1 -> one = "O";
                case 2 -> two = "O";
                case 3 -> three = "O";
                case 4 -> four = "O";
                case 5 -> five = "O";
                case 6 -> six = "O";
                case 7 -> seven = "O";
                case 8 -> eight = "O";
                case 9 -> nine = "O";
                default -> System.out.println("Enter a number from one to nine");
            }

            if (one.equals("O") & two.equals("O") & three.equals("O"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN O");
            }
            else if (four.equals("O") & five.equals("O") & six.equals("O"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN O");
            }
            else if (seven.equals("O") & eight.equals("O") & nine.equals("O"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN O");
            }
            else if (one.equals("O") & four.equals("O") & seven.equals("O"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN O");
            }
            else if (two.equals("O") & five.equals("O") & eight.equals("O"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN O");
            }
            else if (one.equals("O") & five.equals("O") & nine.equals("O"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN O");
            }
            else if (three.equals("O") & five.equals("O") & seven.equals("O"))
            {
                System.out.println("WIN O");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The game did not win");
    }
    public static void cleanScreen()
    {
        System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
        System.out.flush();
    }
  ```

Comment: That string contains ANSI escape sequences saying "move cursor to home" followed by "clear screen".  If that doesn't work, the most likely explanation is that the console that you are writing to doesn't understand / support ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: But I have no idea what the "Dose" game is, what its rules are and what a "house" is.

Comment: It is the same as tic-tac-toe